# NoReverseMatch at /login/ Reverse for 'teacher_dashboard' with arguments '({'teacher':object (2)>},)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:

Tags: python, django, dictionary, routes

**Views.py**

```
def Login(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request , username=username , password=password)
        if user is not None:
            try:
                is_teacher= Teacher.objects.get(profile_id=user.id)
            except Teacher.DoesNotExist:
                is_teacher = None
            if is_teacher is not None:
                login(request , user)
                is_teacher= Teacher.objects.get(profile_id=user.id)
                return redirect('teacher_dashboard' , {'teacher' : is_teacher})
            else:
                login(request , user)
                return redirect('student_dashboard' ) 
    return render (request , "pages/login.html")
```

**urls.py**

```
path('teacher_dashboard/', views.TeacherDashboard , name='teacher_dashboard'),
path('student_dashboard/', views.StudentDashboard , name='student_dashboard'),
```

I want to send  queryset with a html page when its redireted

Comment: Redirect the user with redirect the method now expecting a url which is append to is teacher for example suppose I am redirecting to a page redirect('app:home',{id:1}) this will translate to localhost:8000/home/1 not what you expect as localhost:8000/home so you need to update the path in urls.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 2 errors in your code

1. `return redirect('teacher_dashboard' , {'teacher' : is_teacher})`

since the url doesnt have any parameters

```
path('teacher_dashboard/', views.TeacherDashboard , name='teacher_dashboard'),
```

you need

```
return redirect('teacher_dashboard')
```

2. if you want to redirect to individual teachers dashboard

`return redirect('teacher_dashboard' , {'teacher' : is_teacher.id})`

and url will be

```
path('teacher_dashboard/<int:teacher>', views.TeacherDashboard , name='teacher_dashboard')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your urls.py the path is like this:

```
path('teacher_dashboard/', views.TeacherDashboard , name='teacher_dashboard')
```

Here 'teacher_dashboard/' does not expect anything after the '/'. If you need to pass any parameters then you should make that part of the path specified in urls.py

However, this is not possible. Whatever you need to pass with URL practically comes from browsers and you do not expect the browser to pass a queryset. So bascially what you can do is pass pk of the teacher object in the URL and then get the object in TeachDashboard again

Answer (score 0):

Your URL doesn't accept any arguments. You need to allow the URL to include the data you'll use in the view;

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    path("teacher_dashboard/<int:teacher>/", views.TeacherDashboard, name="teacher_dashboard")
```

The docs for URL paths is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#example) with a good example detailing date based URLs.

You also want to pass just the `Teacher` ID, not the whole object. So your view should do;

```
is_teacher = Teacher.objects.get(profile_id=user.id).id
return redirect('teacher_dashboard' , {'teacher' : is_teacher})
```

On an additional point of the code, if I saw a variable called `is_teacher` I'd expect a `bool` because it either is or isn't a teacher. Therefore I'd suggest you also change that to `teacher = Teacher.objects.get(profile_id=user.id)` because you are getting a teacher object from the database.

Comment: ok i think its a great explanation .... Thanks but markwalker i want to send a queryset i mean all objects to the new view function .

Comment: @MuhammadNaveed You can't do that, you can't pass a queryset to a URL. And your code doesn't reflect that. You're doing a `get` not a `filter`. If you need a queryset you'll have to do that in your view using information passed to it. So if the query will use the `Teacher` ID then pass it like I explained & then create your queryset with the ID passed in.

Comment: ok got it but what can i do to do so that i have fetched a number of records from the database and i want to send this data to the redirected view page

Comment: @MuhammadNaveed you could cache the data using a constant cache key which can be used to retrieve the data in your view. But there must be a simpler/better solution. However this is outside of the scope of this question, so I'd raise a separate question if you can't solve that.